# List with references don't let me continue

Tags: c#, list, reference

i'm doing an c# program and i have the problem when i modify some element of my `list<> menor`, my `list<> mayor` its value will change like my `list<> menor`, here is the code. thank you.

```
List<string[]> listas(List<string[]> mayor, List<string[]> menor)
    {
        List<string[]> may = new List<string[]>(mayor);//here i clone the list mayor
        List<string[]> men = new List<string[]>(menor);//here i clone the list menor

        string[] var_aux = null; ;
        for (int i = 0; i<mayor.Count;i++ )
        {
            if (men.Find(delegate(string[] s) { return s[0] == may.ElementAt(i)[0]; })==null)//here i find all similar elements
            {
                var_aux = new string[4];
                var_aux = may.ElementAt(i);
                var_aux[3] = "0";//here is where i change de element[3]
                men.Add(var_aux);//and here is where the element changed in men, alter the elements in may how can i avoid this?
            }    
        }
        men.Sort((s, t) => String.Compare(s[0], t[0]));
        return men;

    }
```

Comment: So, what's your problem? Does it misbehave? Badmouth you in front of your family? Throw exceptions? If so, what's the message and stack trace? What have you done so far?

Comment: You need to copy each array.

Comment: Are you sure you want to have lists containing string arrays!?

Comment: I guess it's okay, with the string arrays, i dont know, or with what can i use the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
var_aux = new string[4];
```

Is never used, as the following lines replaces it with a reference to an array in `may`:

```
var_aux = may.ElementAt(i);
```

You then modify the contents of this array:

```
var_aux[3] = "0";
```

`var_aux` is the same array as exists in `may`.  If you want a copy, you need to clone the array, for example:

```
var_aux = may.ElementAt(i).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you!!,
all the morning since 7:00 am i'm with that problem, and you in some seconds, you help me, thank you (:, you're a genius